# Get post information in drupal function

Tags: 7, javascript

I posted JSON array from my script using `jQuery.post` , to get the posted data in my drupal module function I am using

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

but is there a better way or a 'drupal-way' to get posted data in a drupal function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Drupal 7, take a look at the module [Content as JSON](http://drupal.org/project/contentasjson). This should take care of the details and put you within the realm of the "drupal-way". There's also the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) which might be overkill for what you're doing.

If you stick with file_get_contents then don't forget json_decode:

```
$received = file_get_contents("drupal://input"); // Use inputstream module.
$received = json_decode($received, TRUE);
```

Then you can play around as much as you'd like with the $received value.

Additionally, the [inputstream module](http://drupal.org/project/inputstream) is invaluable in letting you get to the input stream more than once (if you try using php://input more than once, the second time, and those following, will return NULL).

Comment: not working with "drupal://input", its working with "php://input"